# Requesting Suggestions: Record Video Via Browser - SDKs / APIs etc

Tags: video, webrtc, html5-video

I'm developing an application with Laravel backend. On the front-end, I'm required to ada a facility that lets user record their videos (30-40 seconds max), and save them directly to the server (handled by Laravel).

Since last 10 hours, I'm exploring options and found out useful links that explain how to do this using native HTML elements and some JS - https://web.dev/media-recording-video/

However, I'm wondering if there's an open source solution / SDK available that lets me use advanced browser based video recording functions like

1. Letting user add custom notes/captions to the video-preview before recording
2. Let user re-record the video.
3. Show time remaining etc.

Would appreciate your suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Javascript itself is the only free way I can think of to achieve your list. **(1)** I don't know about _"before recording"_ but if you wait until after the user has recorded then you have pixels for adding text (notes/captions) into the video frames via `<canvas>` editing. **(2)** Re-run your webcam recording function. **(3)** Use a **Timer** to measure time passed and show the number as text (or use as width for some progress bar graphic).

Answer (score 0):

there are a few javascript libraries for client-side stream recording. But these will only provide camera/screen/canvas stream recording functionality. You will have to develop your functionality on top of the media recording library. I don't think any library is available that match your list of functionality.

https://recordrtc.org/
https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder